# How do I get the mlContect ITransformer

Tags: ml.net

The following code will load a saved model and will load 'mlModel' as part of that process.

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();
ITransformer mlModel = mlContext.Model.Load(MLNetModelPath, out var _);
return mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(mlModel);
```

However, If I have just an existing trained mlContext, how do I get the 'ITransformer' from that existing mlContext?

Answer (score 0):

You can load it from a stream instead of file:

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.modeloperationscatalog.load?view=ml-dotnet#microsoft-ml-modeloperationscatalog-load(system-io-stream-microsoft-ml-dataviewschema@))